# client side validation jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a select option field that is populated from the database and I wanted to validate when the user does not select anything and press the submit button. I am not able to get the validation.This is what I have done so far:

For the select option list:

```
<form id="dataForm" method="get" action="">
<b>Year</b>
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT Year_Id,Year_Released FROM {extdb_year} WHERE Only_For_Trend = 0 ORDER BY Year_Released DESC';
$res = db_query($sql);

echo "<select id='Year_Released' name='Year_Released'>
  <option value='-1'>-Select-</option>";
$cnt = 0;
$options = array();
foreach ($res as $row)
{
    $cnt++;
    echo "<option value = '{$row->Year_Id}'";
    if ($cnt==1)
        echo "selected = 'selected'";
    echo ">{$row->Year_Released}</option>";

    $options[$row->Year_Id] = $row->Year_Released;
}
echo "</select>";

?>
<p>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </p>
</form>
```

JQuery code for the validation

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#dataForm").validate({

    rules: {

        Year_Released: {
            required: true
        }

    },
    messages: {

    Year_Released: "You must select a Year."

    }

    });
});
```

Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation code is correct however the first `option` in your `select` element must set the `value` to empty.

```
echo "<select id='Year_Released' name='Year_Released'>
    <option value=''>-Select-</option>";
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/qhprG/**

Answer (score 0):

Put `<option value="">Choose an option</option>` as blank rather than -1

using jquery validation

```
rules: {
select: "required" }
```

Comment: Your first part is correct, I think that @MohanTimilsina had the actual validation options set correctly.

Comment: -1 for showing `rules` that would further break his code. `"select"` is not the `name` of his field, and his rules are already properly defined.